# What are the advantages and the motivation of modports in a SystemVerilog interface?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm new to SystemVerilog.

I am reading the following tutorial:

https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/interfaces/

I'm not sure what are the advantages and the motivation of modports in a SystemVerilog interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modports are used to specify **the direction of signal with respect to a specific module/component**.

They are also used to **restrict access** to certain signals from some modules/classes.

Usually testbench modport contains a bunch of stimulus-driving signals as *output* while the same signals are taken as *input* to the RTL. Also some response signals which are *output* to RTL are taken as *input* to modport.

Consider the example below:

```
interface my_interface(input logic clk, reset);

logic a;
logic b;
logic c;
logic sum;
logic carry;

modport tb  (input sum,carry,  output a,b,c,reset);
modport dut (output sum,carry, input a,b,c,reset);

endinterface
```

Here, testbench is allowed to **drive** `a`,`b` and `c` and `reset`. But it will be erroneous for testbench to drive `sum` and `carry` signals.

If we don't use a modport and accidentally the testbench/RTL drives their respective input signals, then it would result in **unexpected behavior**.

Henceforth modports are generally used to **restrict** the components for driving/sampling signals.

Also they allow the ease of different views of the signals within the interface. One can just look at modport and tell whether it is an input to a particular module/class or an output.

Refer [this link](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/interface3.html) about some more info.

Comment: By tb you mean for example the top moduke of the testbech, and dut is the design module right?

Comment: Yep. It's the top testbench module/class. Just to be explicit, I am referring to "Testbench" module in [this diagram](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/wikifiles/f/f8/Testbench_DUT.png).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, interfaces don't need to capture direction information of signals used between modules or between a module and a testbench.

Example: Master/Slave

Master might need one set of signals as inputs and outputs and slave might need the same set of signals as outputs and inputs. So we use **MOD PORTS** inside the interface to group those signals and specify certain directions.

Mod-port example:

**Interface with modports**

```
interface arb_if (input bit clk);
  logic [1:0] grant, request;
  logic reset;

  modport TEST (output request, reset,
                     input grant,clk);

  modport DUT (input request, reset ,clk,
               output grant);
  modport MONITOR (input request, grant, reset, clk);

  endinterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Though simulators should check for direction during access, it is common for them to ignore it. Synthesis tools look at the direction for implementation.